# regex stop at char not working

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
'"var1":"val1","var2":"val2","var3":"val3"'
```

I want to extract val2 via regex

```
/var2":"(.*)"/g
```

gets everything after var2":"

```
/var2":"(?=[^"])"/g
```

does not get any matches

Comment: Which language / editor do you use? This has an effect on the regex flavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second regex is incorrect and should be

```
/var2":"([^"]*)"/g
```

**Explanation:**

`(?=[^"])"` means: "First make sure that the next character is anything but a `"`. Then match a `"`. That's obviously a) impossible and b) not what you wanted :)

In contrast to that, `([^"]*)` means: "Match any number (including zero) of characters that aren't `"`s, then capture that submatch in group 1."

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there. You need to replace the lookahead with a simple group. Also, need to add a `*` after the character class:

```
var2":"([^"]*)"
```

This will match the whole `"var2":"..."` and the first group will contain `val1`.

I'd add a few optional spaces around the colon ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ufOQT/1)):

```
var2" *: *"([^"]*)"
```

There is a caveat though: the value of the `var2` cannot contain quotes.

Answer (score 0):

seems javascript? please try:  /var2":"(.*?)"/g, or /var2":"(?:[^"]+?)"/g